# How to perform C-M-\ on an azerty keyboard? (and other azerty tips)

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, azerty-keyboard

I've a problem successfully performing the <kbd>C-M-\</kbd> combination on my azerty keyboard.

The main issue is that to hit <kbd>\</kbd> I need to hold down <kbd>alt gr</kbd>, and this seems to mess up the whole thing. I'd be interested to know what's the classical answer to this problem, if there's one that's not 'rebind the command'

And other azerty related tips would interest me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the answer is to type `ESC C-\` (all `M-foo` bindings can be reached by hitting `ESC foo` instead), which is usually a bit easier, tho depending on your keyboard it can still be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try <kbd>AltGr RCtrl Alt _</kbd>?

From [EmacsWiki.org](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AltGrKey):

> The trick is that you must type AltGr as the first key, and Ctrl must be the right control key, not the left one.

Comment: Seems not to work for C-M-\, it just does a C-\. It's already a progress though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had somewhat the same issue using the Atom editor.

In Atom, the "toggle tree-view" shortcut is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>, and with my azerty keyboad any of these <kbd>crtl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> , <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>altgr</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> or even the suggested <kbd>AltGr</kbd> <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt_</kbd> does not work
...

Despite this, I found a working keybinding with the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>- <kbd>*</kbd>  , I don't know why this work but you can verify the key binding you tape with the <kbd>crtl</kbd>- <kbd>.</kbd>  and it shows that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>*</kbd> is actually treated as a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I rebind most of those key bindings, but I have no problem if I hold the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key before the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> (using the other <kbd>Alt</kbd>) That said, I use a bépo keyboard, not an Azerty one (but there are similar problem)